# Diff - exclude case insensitive pattern

Tags: regex, linux, shell, diff

I know to exclude files from diff `diff -x 'pattern' fileA fileB` is used, and for case-insensitive diffs the `-i` option exists.
But using `-xi 'pattern'` still removes only files that match "pattern", but not those that match "PATTERN".

So how can I exclude all files from diff that match case-insensitive "pattern", without using `-x` for each possibility over and over again?

Comment: Change your pattern so that it will match what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`-i` ignores case difference in the files to diff but not in the pattern used for `-x`.

If you want to exclude both the upper and lowercase pattern then pass both to `diff`:

```
diff -x pattern -x PATTERN  ... more arguments
```

Comment: Thats what I've done so far, but is there no better way? I explicitly was looking for another possibility.

Comment: No, there is no other way.